# HealthKit Clinical Health Records - App Crash & Sample JSON Date type details

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

With reference to **HealthKit - Clinical Health Records**, we implemented the following method to fetch the User's clinical records but seems the query is failing and the app is getting crashed every time. Crash reports has not been generated because after querying the data, the app crashes.

We tried the same method with Apple provided sample account and it works fine in the simulator, but it crashes with actual users.

Following is the code snippet we created using this [article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/accessing_a_user_s_clinical_records):

```
func getRecordsForCHRType(type: HKClinicalTypeIdentifier, completion:@escaping ([HKClinicalRecord]?) -> Void) {
    guard let healthRecordType = HKObjectType.clinicalType(forIdentifier: type) else { return }

    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -365), to: Date())!
    let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 0), to: Date())!
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [.strictStartDate])
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    let healthRecordQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: healthRecordType, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in
        guard let actualSamples = samples else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let healthRecordSamples = actualSamples as? [HKClinicalRecord]
        completion(healthRecordSamples)
    }
    HKHealthStore().execute(healthRecordQuery)
   }
```

Can you please help us to identify the issue?

Also, please help us to understand the following different types of dates(in detail) available in sample Clinical Health Records JSON, and is it possible to apply a filter on these dates to narrow down the clinical records response?

1. issued
2. dateRecorded
3. recordDate
4. onset
5. effectiveDatandTime

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Run your app under Xcode on a real device

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, we ran app under xcode but we with sample data provided by HealthKit it works & we are able to fetch EHR.

Problem is we do not have EHR in our devices as its not supported in our region. However for our user who has EHR data & support,  the app is crashing & we cannot get xcode there.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the same question on https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695189

The crash should definitely not happen, can you paste the stack trace here?

Regarding dates, it depends a lot on which resource type you're parsing and also which dates are actually populated in the data model, which depends on data provenance. The "start date" and "end date" have a different meaning, see the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkclinicalrecord:

> Note that the record inherits the HKSample class’s startDate and endDate properties. However, the system does not populate these properties with information from the FHIR data; instead, the startDate and endDate reflect the time and date when the system downloaded the FHIR data to the device.

Comment: Thank you @Pascal, we ran app under xcode simulator but with sample data provided by HealthKit it works & we are able to fetch EHR. Problem is we do not have EHR in our devices as its not supported in our region. However for our user who has EHR data & support, the app is crashing & we cannot get stack trace from end user.